# Why page renders slowly (about 2s)? Django

Tags: python, django

Rendering page takes too long (about 2s)

[image: Page]

[image: Time details]

Even if i return dummy data (without querying) page renders slowly.
But when i return empty dict **tasks_by_day** it takes only ~150ms to load page.

My **question** is why it takes so much time to process so small amount of data and how can I fix this?

Here is my view code:

```
def tasks(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(owner=request.user.id)

    tasks_by_day = {
        "MONDAY" : [tasks[0]],
        "TUESDAY" : [tasks[1]],
        "WEDNESDAY": [tasks[2]],
        "THURSDAY": [tasks[3]],
        "FRIDAY": [tasks[4]],
        "SATURDAY": [tasks[5]],
        "SUNDAY": [tasks[7]]
    }

    return render(request, "todo/tasks.html", {"tasks_by_day": tasks_by_day})
```

Here is my model code:

```
class Task(models.Model):

    # DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_CHOICES, STATUS_CHOICES - constants

    day_of_the_week = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_CHOICES, default=default_day
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=NOT_COMPLETED
    )

    task_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've measured time that needed to execute **tasks** function - it's around 110ms.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can awoid one Join to user table:

```
Task.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id)
```

But The stats says - you works too long with request. Probably you can check some middleware?
By the way, DEBUG_TOOLBAR itself is really heavy element for project. Problem can be there. You can shut off the DEBUG_TOOLBAR and measure only time of your view. It can help.

Comment: I've installed DEBUG_TOOLBAR to check why my page renders slowly. So, the problem is not related to DEBUG_TOOLBAR.
Thanks for advice

Comment: can you publisch the report of the template manager from debug toolbar? or report of the SQLs from debug toolbar? Dont forget to add the settings: 'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel', 'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel', 'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel', 'template_profiler_panel.panels.template.TemplateProfilerPanel'.